# Sum values in mysql table where userid is identical

Tags: mysql

I have read the different answers here on SO, but I am stuck on this question. Please help.

I have this mysql view named "activeuser":

```
userid  COUNT(*)    ACRONYM
1       23          admin
2       2           doe
3       4           tompa
12      4           Marre
13      1           Mia
1       2           admin
3       1           tompa
12      1           Marre
13      1           Mia
2       1           doe
3       1           tompa
12      1           Marre
```

How can I sum the COUNT column so that I get the following wanted result?

```
userid  COUNT(*)    ACRONYM
1       25          admin
2       3           doe
3       6           tompa
12      6           Marre
13      1           Mia
```

EDITED:
I used this query to create the view:

```
CREATE VIEW activeuser AS
(SELECT boats_comments.userid, COUNT(boats_comments.userid), boats_user.acronym, boats_user.email
  FROM boats_comments
  INNER JOIN boats_user
  ON boats_comments.userid = boats_user.id
  GROUP BY boats_comments.userid
  ORDER BY COUNT(boats_comments.userid) DESC)
  UNION ALL
(SELECT boats_answers.userid, COUNT(boats_answers.userid), boats_user.acronym, boats_user.email
  FROM boats_answers
  INNER JOIN boats_user
  ON boats_answers.userid = boats_user.id
  GROUP BY boats_answers.userid
  ORDER BY COUNT(boats_answers.userid) DESC)  
    UNION ALL
  (SELECT boats_questions.userid, COUNT(boats_questions.userid), boats_user.acronym, boats_user.email
  FROM boats_questions
  INNER JOIN boats_user
  ON boats_questions.userid = boats_user.id
  GROUP BY boats_questions.userid
  ORDER BY COUNT(boats_questions.userid) DESC)
```

My goal is to see which users are the most active by checking the number of comments, questions and answers... but I got stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the results in your view has duplicates I guess the underlying code for the view is grouping on something it maybe shouldn't be grouping on.

You can get the results you want by applying SUM to it:

```
select userid, sum("whatever column2 is named") as "Count", Acronym 
from activeuser group by userid, Acronym;
```

Comment: Thanks fo answering! I just edited my question a bit to clarify. Maybe I can use your suggestion on each of the select statements...

Comment: I fiddled a bit more and your answer worked like a charm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select userid, count(*) from activeuser group by userid;
```